# ActionPerformed self-execution

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener, jcombobox

I don't understand why the code in the jcombobox4ActionPerformed is being executed without me clicking on anything. As soon as the program is executed, the "executed" message appears. What is the problem ?

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    public MainFrame()
    { 
        initComponents();
        initComboBox();
        initCourses();

        Course[] cours = new Course[7];

        for (int i = 0; i < cours.length; i++) 
        {
            cours[i] = new Course();
        }

        System.out.println(cours.length);
        System.out.println(cours[0].getNameCourse());


        System.out.println("hey");

    }

private void jComboBox4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    System.out.println("EXECUTED");
}
```

Comment: jComboBox4.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(Course.semester1));
        jComboBox4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try print out the action command from the `ActionEvent` so you know what is firing it

```
private void jComboBox4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    String action = evt.getActionCommand(); 
    System.out.println(action);
}
```

Then if you want certian things to happen only on certain actions you can check that action command

```
private void jComboBox4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    String action = evt.getActionCommand(); 
    System.out.println(action);
    if(action.equals("doBlah")
    {
       System.out.println("Blah blah blah blah");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`actionPerformed` will be executed when ever the selected value of the combo box is changed, but without any more code, its impossible to tell you exactly what might be the cause

Comment: jComboBox4.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(Course.semester1));
        jComboBox4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }

Comment: @Pierre You really should update you question, but do you call `setSelectedItem` at all?  Do you update or modify the model after you've applied it?